# Quantum oracle for boolean function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, quantum-computer

As a math student, I am doing some quantum computing. In the course notes of Ronald de Wolf, he says that any Boolean function $$f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^m$$ can be made into a unitary operation that sends $|z\rangle|0\rangle \to |z\rangle|f(z)\rangle$. But he doesn't mention how or so?

Does anybody have tips or links to a paper where this gets explained?

Comment: What do you mean with "can be made into a unitary operation"?

Comment: With that i mean an operator U that sends |z⟩|0⟩→|z⟩|f(z)⟩ that is unitairy so UU*=I.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The norm is conserved in your transformation. So the operator for it must be unitary.